# Change insert value if value is not in ENUM

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, sql-insert

I want to insert value to Postgres

If I have enum type in a table and I want to change the input value is not in the list
of enum

like

```
create type us_state as enum ('AL', ..., 'NULL');

insert into user (name, state)
values ('Bob', 'AA')
conflict on state is not valid us_state update value = 'NULL'
```

how can I use conditional insert or update the value while inserting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as concerned, `on conflict` does not recognize enum violations. The [`INSERT` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) says:

> The optional `ON CONFLICT` clause specifies an alternative action to raising a unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error.

Unfortunately an enum type does not fall in that category (same applies to check constraints, which otherwise could have been a possible solution here).

We could resort the trick of listing the enum values with `enum_range()`, then using that in a conditional expression:

```
insert into users(name, state) 
select 
    name, 
    case when state = any(enum_range(null::us_state)::name[]) 
        then state::us_state 
    end
from (values ('Bob', 'AA')) t(name, state)
```

Note that this produces a `NULL` value when the given value does not exists in the enum, rather than an arbitratry string such as `'NULL'`; this looks to me like the proper way to represent unmatched values.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1e9cf8b3454308a678b547e84d0d6281)**:

```
create type us_state as enum ('AL', 'WA');
create table users(name text, state us_state);

-- an attempt with "on conflict"
insert into users (name, state) values ('Bob', 'AA') on conflict(state) do nothing
-- ERROR:  invalid input value for enum us_state: "AA";
-- LINE 1: insert into users (name, state) values ('Bob', 'AA') on conf...

-- new query
insert into users(name, state) 
select 
    name, 
    case when state = any(enum_range(null::us_state)::name[]) 
        then state::us_state 
    end
from (values ('Bob', 'AA'), ('Bill', 'AL')) t(name, state);
-- 2 rows affected

select * from users;
```

```
name | state
:--- | :----
Bob  | null 
Bill | AL
```

Comment: nice "trick":) (`enum_range`!) ..for the "most flexibility" (null vs 'null'), querying `coalesce( pg_type join pg_enum)` would be possible.(?)